# REGEX and GREP -- Search string including optional and static words

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I am trying to formulate a regex expression for use with grep such that I find a static word present at the beginning of each line, followed by only one word from a list of options.

That is, I matches I want are of the form: `StaticWord-opt1`, `StaticWord-opt2`, etc.

This *almost* works:

`grep -E "^StaticWord-[(opt1)?(opt2)?(opt3)?]+" fileToCheck`

But I get matches like: `StaticWord-opt1(`, `StaticWord-p`, and `StaticWord-1`

Since a valid match is only if we have a single instance of op1, opt2, or opt3, I changed the expression to:

`grep -E "^StaticWord-[(opt1)?(opt2)?(opt3)?]{1}" fileToCheck`

At which point I get only matches like the latter two of the list outlined above.

My logic for the expression is "`StaticWord-` is anchored at the beginning `^` followed by any of the following `[ ]` groups `( )`, each of which may or may not be present `?`. Lastly, we *must* have only one from the list `{1}`.

Comment: `^StaticWord-(opt1|opt2|opt3)`

Comment: @don_crissti, Sorry. opt1, opt2, and opt3.

Comment: Should "StaticWord-opt1morestuff" match or not match? (Should the line end with opt1, opt2, or opt3?)

Comment: You're getting bad results because you're using brackets which do something different. Just do `(opt1|opt2|opt3)` without the brackets like @jordanm suggested.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, My requirements are only that `StaticWord-opt1` be present. Using what was suggested in the comments above I was able to achieve that. What must be changed in order to prevent further matches?

Comment: @CyprianGuerra, I thought the brackets meant "match any character contained in the set". And, since I grouped each of the items listed between the brackets, I figured it would work.

Comment: @sherrellbc grouping doesn't work in set definition, what you were doing is definig a set that contains `opt)(?123` and matching any of its elements.

Comment: @sherrellbc you use `[]` bracket-expressions or character classes when you want to match any of a set of characters.  e.g. if you wanted to match one of the literal strings `opt1`, `opt2`, or `opt3` you could do `(opt1|opt2|opt3)` OR you could do `opt[123]` - which is "opt" followed by either 1 or 2 or 3.  and, of course, you can use both `()` and `[]` - e.g. `(opt[123]|foo|bar)`

Answer (score 2):

In case jordanm doesn't convert their comment to an answer, I'll expand on it:

You want to use the `|` character to say "opt1 or opt2 or opt3". Additionally, if you only want *one* of those to appear, you do *not* want to use `+`, which means "one or **more**". This gets you closer:

```
grep -E "^StaticWord-(opt1|opt2|opt3)" fileToCheck
```

... but then you have the question about the remainder of the line. If you want nothing else on the line, use:

```
grep -E "^StaticWord-(opt1|opt2|opt3)\$" fileToCheck
```

(where I escaped the dollar sign from the shell so that `grep` sees it as the end-of-line marker).